# How do you access a lit-element render root after overriding createRenderRoot?

Tags: typescript, lit-element

I've been playing around with lit-element, and I want to grab my custom element to run a getElementById. The only examples I can find use the shadow root (since that's the recommended way to use lit-element). How do you get access to your custom element to run a query on just your element?

```js
import { LitElement, html } 
from 'https://unpkg.com/lit-element/lit-element.js?module';

class RenderRootTest extends LitElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  render () {
    const renderRoot = this.shadowRoot; //Won't work, because I'm overriding the shadowroot
    return html`
      <div>Rendered</div>
      ${renderRoot ? 
        html`<div>Render root found</div>` :
        html``
      }
    `;
  }
  createRenderRoot() {
    return this;
  }
}

customElements.define('render-root-test', RenderRootTest);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself after enough tinkering. You can either use `this.renderRoot` or just `this`. However, note that certain methods such as `.getElementById` don't seem to exist. If anyone has any additional details on this topic, I would appreciate it.

ex.

```
import { LitElement, html } 
from 'https://unpkg.com/lit-element/lit-element.js?module';

class RenderRootTest extends LitElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  render () {
    const renderRoot = this.renderRoot;
    return html`
      <div>Rendered</div>
      ${renderRoot ? 
        html`<div>Render root found</div>` :
        html``
      }
    `;
  }
  createRenderRoot() {
    return this;
  }
}

customElements.define('render-root-test', RenderRootTest);
```

Comment: `getElementById` is a method that [exists](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nonelementparentnode)  on Document and DocumentFragment objects. ShadowRoot [implements](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#shadowroot) DocumentFragment, so ShadowRoot objects have `getElementById`. In your example, `renderRoot` is an instance of RenderRootTest, which extends LitElement, so the methods you can call on it are those defined by LitElement and, by, extension, HTMLElement. Neither of those implement Document or DocumentFragment, so they don't have `getElementById`.

Comment: (cont.) TL;DR: You can't call `getElementById` on your custom element or its `renderRoot` for the same reason you can't call it on, say, a `<div>`. It doesn't implement that method.

Answer (score 2):

Just reference `this` which is the instance of the custom element. The `shadowRoot` is created and returned by LitElement's `createRenderRoot()` so if you don't create one and instead of `this.shadowRoot` return `this`--which is the node itself--that is what the content is rendered into, there is no shadowRoot.